# search through json objects based on unique id

Tags: json, node.js

I'm having a lot of like below json objects. That i would like to be able to get by for instance `lookup["22"]` and then get below object. However i'm not sure what is the best way and how effective it is?

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": "22",
        "Email": "a@test.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "Email": "test@test.com"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) you can loop your array and find first item matching condition. So that you can write a function to do lookup (used ES6 syntax):

```
const lookup = id => data.find(d => d.id === id);
lookup('22');
```

It is not supported by all environments, but it should work in node.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have JSON objects that are in-memory and not stored in a way that allows you to create a [lookup index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).

The naïve solution is to use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which will loop through the entire collection, giving us O(n) time on each lookup. However, if you can structure *how* this JSON is formatted, you might save yourself some time in the long run. Consider creating a structure like this if you can guarantee unique ids:

```
const data = {
    "22": {
        "id": "22",
        "Email": "a@test.com"
    },
    "11": {
        "id": "11",
        "Email": "test@test.com"
    }
}
```

And then you can do as you showed above: `data[id]`. If you're getting this data from a rigid API, it might still be worth it to manually mutate your data if you're doing many lookups as indexing costs the same amount of time as looking up a single document.

Comment: yes wish i could that, but this is an rest api, that i'm using